# .htaccess mod_rewrite to match languages subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I need to configure subdomains on my website for multilanguage support. I don't have much knowledge of .htaccess configuration, I only know what the file I've been using so far does and that's it.
So I redirect to my public folder and let everything go through my router (index.php) while I'm cleaning the url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I'm building a multilanguage website and I would like to have my path formatted like

```
en.domain.com

es.domain.com
```

Anyone out there can help me with this?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your htaccess file in your question. Could you please also add from which url TO which url you want to redirect or rewrite for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding following in your Apache vhost file(based on your shown samples) and restart apache once. Fair warning I haven't tested this one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName en.domain.com 
   DocumentRoot "your_path"
   <Directory "your_path">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName es.domain.com
   DocumentRoot "your_another_path"
   <Directory "your_another_path">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Now I get access forbidden, unable to read hatches file.

Comment: @dnldevs, could you please do mention which URL you are hitting and getting error here(sample url will help here).

Comment: I just want domain.com to be redirected to en.domain.com which is default. Without losing router redirect that I already have in my .htaccess file

Comment: @dnldevs, ok, are you getting an error etc by these rules?

Comment: No, I just hit the domain.com which is not what I want